# Why is Baire Category Important in the Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question

Proofs for the Open Mapping Theorem that I've seen use the Baire Category Theorem to produce an open set in $Y$ that is in the image of some scaled ball from $X$. I think I'm missing a technical point though -- why can't we take for granted that an open subset is available in the image?

Comment: This seems like an absurd question. All things in mathematics must be justified. You can't just take things for granted because you feel like it.

Comment: I assume you mean 'why isn't it obvious?' not 'why does it need to be justified?' but you haven't explained why you think it's obvious.

Comment: okay, as I tried to explain why I thought it was obvious, I realized there was something to check. The image of a ball will be non-empty in $Y$, but ensuring that the image has an interior is non-trivial. A function from the reals into the rational numbers is a function whose image has an empty interior.

Comment: @yoshi yep, sounds like you get it now.